# Deployement not Rendering KendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, web-deployment

**VS2012 asp.net MVC4 c#, Internet Application with KendoUI Implementation.**

The easiest way to say it is that My website looks like this

> - localy on the Development machine:

[image]

> - And like this deployed:

[image]

I have checked sever KendoUI forums, all of them pointing to Images missing... I checked and even copied over my deployment files, Files and Images are there, KendoUI Scripts are there.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that for some reason the Kendo JavaScript or CSS files are missing on your deployment server. You can verify this by checking your browser's developer console (the "Network" tab) for any failing HTTP requests (404 status code). In a word make sure the Kendo JS and CSS files are being deployed successfully.

Comment: `?v=pzyG6PIK9SK-SBYrjx_9W4M2LE67QlprY627wUj4x9M1
/Content/kendo` is what I'm seeing in the name path and `http://cls-og.com/Content/kendo?v=pzyG6PIK9SK-SBYrjx_9W4M2LE67QlprY627wUj4x9M1
Redirect` for the initiator... Found out there attached to the Bundle part of my Layout view calling both `kendo.common.min.css` and `kendo.default.min.css` , they both have full permissions but still show a `403 no perm`. However i do remember reading something about `Json`, wich i cannot find in the files anywhere is there a trick to `Json` and why it would only work on the Dev machine?

Comment: This isn't related with Json. Check online for problems related with ASP.NET Bundle permissions.

Comment: The fix was: Updating `WebOptimization`, adding `bundles.DirectoryFilter.Clear();` and the `.Ignore` for it. This allowed the `.min` `kendoUI` files to be read correctly.

Comment: http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved - this is very good documentation on the matter

Answer (score 1):

You need to add kendo scripts directly in the header of your layout.

```
<head>
   <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
</head>
```